# Pandas the value 1 year ago is lower

Tags: python, pandas, date

```
df['Inflation'] = pd.read_csv('INFLATION_EUR.csv', header=None, names=['Date', 'Value'])['Value']
df['EURUSD'] = pd.read_csv('DEXUSEU.csv', header=None, names=['Date', 'Value'])['Value']
df = df.set_index('Date')
df['Gerber'] = 0
```

The data looks like this:

```
Date            Interest   Inflation  EURUSD      Gerber
...              ...        ...          ...       ...
01/31/2019      3.50       1.84        1.329       0
02/28/2019      3.50       1.84        1.317       0
03/31/2019      3.75       1.94        1.309       0
04/30/2019      3.75       1.91        1.300       0
05/31/2019      3.75       1.87        1.302       0
...              ...        ...          ...       ...
08/31/2019      0.00       1.24        1.375       0
09/30/2019      0.00       1.00        1.381       0
10/31/2019      0.00       0.91        1.370       0
11/30/2019      0.00       0.77        1.369       0
12/31/2019      0.00        0          1.362       0
..
```

I need to check if the inflation is lower than 1 year ago (12 months), in that case set Gerber to 1 instead of 0. This goes for each row. The data is monthly.

The last row should be:

```
12/31/2019      0.00        0          1.362       1
```

since inflation 01/31/2019 was 1.84, i.e. higher than 0. The data goes from 1990 to 2019.

How can I do this? I tried this:

```
df['Gerber'] = df['Inflation'].rolling(12).apply(lambda x: 1 if (x[0] < x[-1]) else 0)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and put some sample input and expected output? Also, why February (`02/31/2007`) has 31 days?

Comment: I’m voting to close this for being too broad and generic. There is no evidence of any attempt.

Comment: I added my try. Let me know if I can explain in more detail.